# SELECT with different values for foreign key

Tags: mysql, database

I have 2 tables:

```
Products(..., category_id)
Categories(id, name, level_1_parent_id, level_2_parent_id)
```

`category_id` is foreign key for `Categories(id)`

If it's first level category `level_1_parent_id` is NULL, 
If second level category `level_2_parent_id` is NULL, `level_1_parent_id` is set, 
if third level both are set.

I'm selecting products like this

```
SELECT *
FROM Products
WHERE category_id = ${category_id}
```

What I need to achieve: 
Select products from child categories if its first or second level category.

So for example if I'm selecting from category with `id == 1` (which is first level id) I want to select products with `category_id` equals `1` and other categories with `level_1_parent_id == 1` and the same for second level category.

Is that possible somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can use nested query here.

> SELECT * FROM Products WHERE category_id = ${category_id} or
>    category_id in (select distinct id from Categories where  level_1_parent_id = ${category_id} or level_2_parent_id = ${category_id})

Answer (score 0):

You get the category list by joining the table to itself first, then get the products associated with each of the categories found. Note the use of alias's for each of the tables in the from and join clauses.

```
SELECT *
FROM Categories c1
LEFT JOIN Categories c2
    ON c2.level_1_parent_id = c1.id
LEFT JOIN Categories c3
    ON c3.level_1_parent_id = c1.id AND c3.level_2_parent_id = c2.id
JOIN Products p
    ON p.category_id = c1.id OR p.category_id = c2.id OR p.category_id = c3.id
WHERE c1.category_id = ${category_id}
```